# How to get the corresponding WPF theme with the current Windows theme?

Tags: wpf, windows, operating-system, themes, default

Let's say in my application, there are two regions: 1) used customized theme, and 2) used the system theme (the theme selected by the user in his Windows OS). Region 1 uses the customized themes whilst Region 2 uses the default themes.

The official default WPF themes can be downloaded [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812). What I need is to know the current theme that the wPF Presntation Library has applied to my default controls - so that I can activate it at runtime for UI in region 2.

If you know how, please share. Any helps are all very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using data trigger to adjust style according to the default style of the application.

Add namespace reference xmlns:shell=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell at appropriate place.

setters....

Enjoy !!!

Comment: Correction: Using data trigger to adjust style in xaml according to the default Theme of the application.  Detect current theme of the WPF application.

Comment: You can edit your answer by clicking `edit` link at the end of your post